# Mysterious attribute showing up in HTML in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a strange attribute that's showing up in my <kbd>F12</kbd> developer tools in IE10.  The test case I've been using is about:blank.  This is supposed to be a completely minimal HTML page.

When I look at the DOM for this page, I see `<html dpWbAdvi="2781">`.  In particular that attribute seems wrong.  It also appears on every other page I visit.

So far, I've disabled every Add-on in the "Manage add-ons" menu item, and searched my registry for dpWbAdvi.  This kind of smells like malware, but I'm stuck.  Has anyone heard of this?

**Edit:**

`<html>foo</html>` still exhibits the problem.  Here's the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

**Edit 2:**

I've run hijackthis, and removed every BHO reference, even the ones that sound plausibly useful. I've already disabled all add-ons through IE's menu.  I'm still seeing the same behavior.  I'm in the process of running a full MS Security Essentials scan as well.

Comment: I'd say malware: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dpWbAdvi

Comment: Try it with a truly minimal page: `<html>foo</html>`, what do you see? Is the tag inserted?

Comment: Is it always the same number?

Comment: @Synetech: yes, it's always exactly `dpWbAdvi="2781"`.

Comment: Weird, it does sound like malware. I guess it is also IE specific right? Does it also appear if you just view the source through IE without going into the DOM?

Comment: Have you tested other browsers? I’m wondering if it is something in IE or in your network connection…

Comment: Sounds like Web Advisor

Comment: Plain view-source shows no attribute.  Neither does Chrome.  So the problem seems not to be on the network.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, what’s that? Googling `Web Advisor` brings up nothing specific, and Googling the attribute brings only a single hit on a Chinese site.

Comment: @recursive, great, you’ve just narrowed it down tremendously. Now try disabling every addin and BHO that you can. Try [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and [HijackThis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/) to get a view of what’s hooking into IE.

Comment: @Synetech: No idea what it is, it just *sounds* like it :D

Comment: Enter your HKT log at the [analyzer](http://www.hijackthis.de/) for a quick overview of statistics for your items. Also check the IE tab of Autoruns.

Comment: @Synetech: My hjt log is pastebin.com/u1e9A8Rr and I deleted everything from the autoruns' IE tab and rebooted.  Behavior is unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into this while troubleshooting an issue for the client. The attribute is being injected onto the page by a process associated with a program called HP ProtectTools, which is crapware preinstalled on Hewlett-Packard machines.

Your question was actually very helpful to me, because I cross-referenced your HiJackThis log with the client's list of installed software. I noticed the entry for DPAgent.exe in your log and found that you had the same HP security suite as the client.

I'm happy to report that uninstalling HP ProtectTools resolved the issue completely.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's some sort of malware.
Please run HiJackThis http://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/ and post the logfile here.
Also please run ccleaner http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds and take a look at the values in the "autostart" -> "Internet explorer" thingy.

Edit: What kind of antivirus are you running? Is there an option to disable "web security" or something?

Comment: hjt log is here: http://pastebin.com/u1e9A8Rr  I'm running MS Security Essentials.

Comment: Actually, I recommend against posting logs on the Internet; they often contain things like user and directory names, installed hardware and software, and other things that it would be better not to publicize.

Answer (score -1):

I got this email source, if I go to  omoidol.com/wp-content/7c334.php I find that tag:

To: 88888888
Subject: 
X-PHP-Script: omoidol.com/wp-content/7c334.php for 127.0.0.1
From: 
X-Mailer: SayMailSMTP
Reply-To: 
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary="----------137459387551EEA3530301B"
Return-Path: admin@omoidol.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 23 Jul 2013 15:38:47.0040 (UTC) FILETIME=[B88F7800:01CE87BA]